# How to upload the binary to app store?

Tags: iphone

Please answer my query,my application is a server based application and only when connected to the server it can navigate to other screens,else the user will be restricted to only one screen.If i upload this binary,how could apple test it without a server.Do i give them the server also or do apple follow someother method of reviewing.

Please help me out.

Comment: the server application is developed by us.So do we have to give the server binary also for the testing.

Answer (score 1):

Make a demo site and provide the details to them in the form. Make sure that they can reach it from their site, otherwise you will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give them info/usernames/passwords etc to test with, you do this when you specify your app details when submitting

Comment: the server application is developed by us.So do we have to give the server binary also for the testing.

Comment: Only ever used servers available over the internet.  If it's intended to say, discover one on a LAN then you probably would but if it's anything complex requiring them to do loads of work I doubt they'd look at it in any reasonable time frame.  I'd recommend having a server on the internet for them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide Apple with all of the details necessary to connect to the environment that you've set up for the application. See page 47 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) for more details.

Comment: They did not ask for the supporting hardware